# Problem with sequence of numbers. Each new number is calculated by subtracting the first digit from the current number

Tags: c, sequence

For example, if a starting number is 100 and an ending number of 50, the sequence would be:
99, 90, 81, 73, 66, 60, 54, 49. So there are 8 numbers in sequence.

I am trying to write this program, but I am not sure where to start.
How do I tell the computer to scan the first digit of an inputted number?

I can take care of the rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the left most digit of the number (ex `2` in `234`). There are a few ways to do this. One way is to divide by 10 raised to the n-1 power, where n is the number of digits. In the example, `234`, there are 3 digits, so divide by 10^3-1 or 10^2 which is 100 and, for integers, `234 / 100 = 2`.

To get the power of 10, you can use the `log10()` function:

```
#include <math.h>
...
int power10 = floor(log10(i));
int msd = (int)(i / pow(10, power10));
```

Another option is to keep dividing by 10 until you get to 0, storing the next to last result.

```
int msd, tmp = i;
do {
    msd = tmp;   // Store result before dividing
    tmp /= 10;
} while (tmp > 0);
```

Lastly, you could convert the number to a string, and just use indexing:

```
char s[32];
sprintf(s, "%d", i);
// If i=234, s = "123" and s[0] = '2', s[1] = '3', s[2] = '4'
// Convert to int by subtracting '0'
int msd = i[0] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple, all integer algorithm to get the most significant digit of a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// msd -- most significant digit
int
msd(int val)
{
    int dig = 0;

    for (;  val != 0;  val /= 10)
        dig = val % 10;

    return dig;
}

void
all(int beg,int end)
{
    int cur;

    cur = beg;

    while (cur > end) {
        int old = cur;
        int dig = msd(cur);
        cur -= dig;
        printf("old=%d dig=%d cur=%d\n",old,dig,cur);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    all(100,50);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
old=100 dig=1 cur=99
old=99 dig=9 cur=90
old=90 dig=9 cur=81
old=81 dig=8 cur=73
old=73 dig=7 cur=66
old=66 dig=6 cur=60
old=60 dig=6 cur=54
old=54 dig=5 cur=49
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most significant digit of a positive number in any base with this simple function:

```
int most_significant_digit(int n, int base) {
    // assuming n >= 0 and base >= 2
    while (n >= base)
        n /= base;
    return n;
}
```